# Mongoose model.find() returns an empty collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this model

```
const BlockModel = Mongoose.model('blocks', {    
    height: Number,
    size: Number,
    time: Number
})
```

And this API call (hapi.js)

```
server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/api/blockinfo",
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        await BlockModel.deleteMany({})
        const { res, payload } = await Wreck.get('https://someurl');
        let myJson = JSON.parse(payload.toString()).blocks
        // console.log(myJson)
        for (let i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
            var block = new BlockModel({
                height: myJson[i].height,
                size: myJson[i].size,
                time: myJson[i].time
            });
            block.save();
        }

       console.log(BlockModel.find({}))  
       return  BlockModel.find({});  //returns an empty array

    }
})
```

So it basically deletes the content of the collection and then uploads new data to it. I want to return that collection so it's displayed in my API. But `BlockModel.find({})` is returning an empty collection although I can check that the collection isn't empty if I use the mongo console and check

```
db.blocks.find({})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `await` to the `save` call,

```
await block.save();
```

Comment: Strange, it will work in the return, but only If i dont delete the previous ```console.log(await BlockModel.find({}))```  , which I want to delete

Comment: Remove the console.log and also check the save call `await block.save();` . It should have happened.

Comment: @ShivamPandey you mean that OP have to do `return  await BlockModel.find({});` ?

Comment: @ShivamPandey besides of that he ment that blocks.save() should have an await too

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Yes

Comment: So it's wrong. The function is an `async` function. There is no need to `return await`. Return a `Promise` is good enough. Problem was with the `await save` and the `console.log(await BlockModel.find({}))`

Comment: @ShivamPandey you should edit your answer to give the correct correction to OP issue :)

Comment: Please change your answer, the issue was with ```await block.save()```  , the return shouldnt have an await

Comment: `return await aPromise` is same `return aPromise`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the blocks you wants using [insertMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany). This method will returns you directly the newly inserted data.

```
async(request, h) => {
  await BlockModel.deleteMany({});

  const {
    res,
    payload
  } = await Wreck.get('https://someurl');

  const myJson = JSON.parse(payload.toString()).blocks

  // Create new items and save them into the database.
  // insertMany returns the added blocks
  return BlockModel.insertMany(myJson.map(x => ({
    height: x.height,
    size: x.size,
    time: x.time
  })));
}
```

---

---

If myJson looks like :

```
[{
  height,
  size,
  time,
}]
```

You can turn the code into :

```
async(request, h) => {
  await BlockModel.deleteMany({});

  const {
    res,
    payload
  } = await Wreck.get('https://someurl');

  const myJson = JSON.parse(payload.toString()).blocks

  // Create new items and save them into the database.
  // insertMany returns the added blocks
  return BlockModel.insertMany(myJson);
}
```

Comment: This approach is much better here `insertMany`. OP should use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
await block.save();
// wait to save block before return
// ....

const blocks = await BlockModel.find({})
console.log(blocks)  
return blocks;
```

I think your code run is ok (not `console.log`) because you call:

```
console.log(BlockModel.find({}))
```

It will log a Promise, not object expect.

We store it into one variable because we don't need to call the query twice.

Comment: It solves half of the problem. The main issue is with the asynchronous `block.save(); `